# Working with managed files in Unlocked Packages

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, picklist, unlocked-package

I am working on an org where we are building a custom solution on top of a managed package. The managed package provides the base objects and a number of standard fields. I have extended this with additional objects, fields, automation, etc. and have also made some adjustments to managed components themselves, such as setting field history tracking, OWDs, and search filters on managed objects or adding picklist values to managed fields.

When I try to create an unlocked package from the metadata, it complains that the files from the managed package are already in another package:

"You're trying to include CustomObject Y in Package X. This component already exists in Package null, which Package X depends on. You can't include the same component in both packages."

Other components in my package are dependent on these files (e.g. record types and flows depend on picklist values defined on managed fields), so I can't create the package without the picklist values, but I can't include the picklist values in a package because they are on managed fields. This issue I can resolve by refactoring the solution to use custom picklists.

The solution also includes custom report types and reports of managed objects with activities. The managed objects do not have activities activated by default in the package. Since activating activities on the managed object requires an update to the object definition, I can't think of a way to refactor this to remove the dependency.

What is the best practice regarding managing customisation of managed files in relation to unlocked packaging? Does this mean that all namespaced files (and by extension everything that references them)  must be part of the unpackaged layer? Is there something else here that I am missing?

Comment: Did you add the managed package as a dependency to the unlocked package in your sfdx-project.json file?

Comment: Yes, we did. The issue is that the dependency is on a "vanilla" install of the managed package, so custom components that are dependent on unmodified managed components (e.g. a custom field on a managed object) package correctly, but those that that are dependent on a modification (e.g. additional picklist values) throw errors.

Comment: This is very interesting question, have you tried to delete unnecessary metadata and keep only necessary metadata? For example, if it complains for the Custom Object Y, have you tried to delete file CustomObjectY__c.object-meta.xml but keep the folder with the record types and flows?

Comment: Removing all of the managed files from the project results in the package complaining that a dependency is missing ("Picklist value: ValueX in picklist: CustomFieldY not found") because the vanilla version of the managed package does not include this value. Leaving the customised managed files in the project results in the error described above "You're trying to include CustomField Y in Package X. This component already exists in Package null, which Package X depends on. You can't include the same component in both packages."